# Ubuntu booting up slow and not properly

Tags: boot, 16.04

One day I booted up my computer normally, and it the boot up process was slower than normal. When my computer boots up the cursor and the desktop were gone. The only thing there was the utility bar. After a while Ubuntu finished loading, but I could not connect to my wifi. The wifi button in the top right of the screen was gone. So I opened up the 'Network Application' as I call it, and it crashes every time I mess around with it. I assume the system got messed up somehow. How would I keep my files and fix the issues?